# Powerpoint - Bind character-size formatting of side-by-side placeholders to each other

Tags: formatting, powerpoint, placeholder, powerpoint-2010

Often, I run into the problem that I have to create slides with two text placeholders (two column-layout, side-by-side).

When my text overruns the "capacity" of a placeholder, the text gets automatically resized in that specific placeholder.

My problem is: The text in the other placeholder does not get resized automagically.  I.e. I would like to bind (or link) the character size formatting of the placeholders to each other such that if the text gets resized in one placeholder the other text in the other placeholder gets resized too.

Is this possible?  If not, what opportunities do exist?

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the layouts that provides two columns of text (Two Content or Comparison).  Or add your own text box, set it to two columns and to auto-fit text to placeholder.

Otherwise, you'd need to add code to trap the selection change event, and if the previous selected shape was one that was "bound" to another, do whatever adjustments are needed.  It's not a simple task, but it can be done.